# If conditional stop closing of modal on outside click in React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have modal. I use this modal why upload video. So when ı upload video, I waiting for it to upload. While continuing uploading, I want to stop closing of modal on outside click, but while not uploading then can be close.

```
<Modal
    show={show}
    onHide={handleClose}
    backdrop="static"
    keyboard={false}>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Do this modal component is a custom modal or a react UI library Modal?

Comment: Yes custom modal  https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/#rb-docs-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need more details about your code but generally you have to check uploading status on `handleClose` like so

```
handleClose = () => {
    if(uploading) {
        return false 
    } else {
        setShow(false)
    }

}
```